# djangoのバージョンを確認するときにエラーが発生する: No module named django

Tags: python, django

「python django 開発入門」という本で勉強しています。

pythonをインストールし、次にdjangoをインストールした後にdjangoのバージョンを確認した結果、
以下のエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
No module named django
```

これは、djangoが正しくインストールされていないと思うのですが、どのような対処をすればよいのでしょうか？

回答よろしくお願いいたします。

### 追記

OSはWindowsです。
Pythonは公式のホームページからインストールしました。
コマンドプロンプトで、python -m venvコマンドを実行し、仮想環境を構築した後、pipコマンドでDjangoをインストールしました。

Comment: おっしゃるように正しくインストールされていないのだと思います。Python や django をどのようにインストールしたのかも質問文に書いて頂けませんでしょうか。質問文下の「編集」より自由に追記が可能です :)

Comment: pytyohは公式のホームページからインストールしました。djangoはpipコマンドを使いインストールしました。

Comment: OSが何かなどの環境情報を教えていただくことも可能ですか？　たとえば Windows か macOS かでは公式ホームページ https://www.python.org/ からのインストール方法が異なります。

Comment: OSはWindowsです。コマンドプロンプトで、python -m venvコマンドを実行し、仮想環境を構築した後、pipコマンドでDjangoをインストールしました。

Comment: 「python -m venvコマンドを実行し、仮想環境を構築した後」←この情報が無茶苦茶重要そうです……！　エラーが発生したときにどのようなコマンドを実行しましたか？　そのコマンドは仮想環境の下で実行されていますか？

Comment: > cd venv 仮想環境名￥Scriptsを実行し、> activate.batを実行し、deactivateコマンドを実行しました。　エラーが発生したときは、仮想環境に入った後python -m django ---versionを実行したら、No module named djangoというのが出てきました。

Comment: なぜ deactivate したのかよく分からなかったのですが、`python -m django --version` を実行したのは activate した直後でしょうか？　仮想環境に入った後 `pip list` コマンドを実行することでインストールされたパッケージの一覧を見ることができます。その一覧に `django` はありますでしょうか。

Comment: PycharmのProject Intepreterからインストールすればエラーが起こらなくなりました。お手数おかけしました。

Comment: むむっなるほど、もしよければ手順を[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)いただけないでしょうか。後から同じ問題で困った方の助けになるかもしれません。少し待てば自分の回答を自分で承認することもできるようになります。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。